# PHP MySQL Different results between query on web server and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a field that looks like this:

> Intelligence: 0/75

I have a form that users can search the value of this string. On my live web server, this is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL AND `file` REGEXP CONCAT('Intelligence(: | : )([', :var2, '-9]|[0-9]{2,3})[ ]{0,1}/[ ]{0,1}([', :var2, '-9]|[0-9]{1,3})')
$var2 = $_POST['int'];
$stmt->bindValue(':var2', $var2);
```

`:var2` is the $_POST value. I've been using the case of `4`. This is the literal regexp when 4 is plugged in:

```
Intelligence(: | : )([4-9]|[0-9]{2,3})[ ]{0,1}/[ ]{0,1}([4-9]|[0-9]{1,3})
```

Since the field in my database is `Intelligence: 0/75` this query shouldn't yield any results. But it does, on my live web server. It returns the field `Intelligence: 0/75`.

If I go and run this EXACT query in phpmyadmin, I get no results. I've lined up the query from phpmyadmin and my server in my text editor and they're identical. Just so I'm not crazy, here's the query copy/pasted from phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT *
FROM `test`
WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL
AND `file`
REGEXP CONCAT( 'Intelligence(: | : )([4-9]|[0-9]{2,3})[ ]{0,1}/[ ]{0,1}([4-9]|[0-9]{1,3})' )
```

Can anyone see why the hell this is yielding two diff. results?

**Update:**

I think I've narrowed it down to the PHP. If I change the value being bound to `:var2`, to like

```
$stmt->bindValue(':var2', '6284');
```

The results are the same. All rows with `Intelligence: 0/75` are returned.

If I delete the `bindValue` code, so there is nothing being bound to :var2, the results are still the same!

print_r($stmt) =

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL AND `file` REGEXP
                    CONCAT('(INT:[  ]{1,2}([', :var2, '-9]|[0-9]{2,3})[  ]{1,2}/[  ]{1,2}([', :var2, '-9]|[0-9]{1,3})|Intelligence(: | : )([', :var2, '-9]|[0-9]{2,3})[ ]{0,1}/[ ]{0,1}([', :var2, '-9]|[0-9]{1,3}))')
```

Comment: Maybe you should regex it in php and not in mySQL.

Comment: @MarkGarcia I did, it's the last example in my original post.

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(':var2', $var2);` where is var2 in the query you gave us?

Comment: @MateiMihai Sorry , typo. updated post.

Comment: Couldn't see anything wrong with this, PDO or mySQL messing it up. It could be something else - can you post a little more code, just to check everything else is going right - e.g. you're looking at the right results set, for example, or executing the right query - just in case you missed it while concentrating on the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Norse,

When you say " on my live web server", do you mean on your web page rendered by PHP, or the SQL command line utility ?

Make the **sql demon log the queries**. You will be able to compare what *exact* queries are executed !
[log query (MySQL doc)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

You seem to have more unit of data in the file column. In general, try to have one unit of data in each column, and respect as much as possible the Normal Forms ([Database_normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)) .  You will have faster, simpler query, with no regex. However, it may not be possible in your case.

Comment: I tried logging queries in mySQL to see if PDO was corrupting it, and it wasn't. So I did a `SELECT CONCAT...` to check mysql wasn't messing the concat, and it wasn't. Did you see anything different?

Comment: So you are logging the queries. You execute the first method. Then you execute the second one 5 minutes later. You see distinctively the two queries that are executed in the log file that you have put in the demon parameter. And they are exactly the same?

Comment: I did using the code provided by the OP - via PDO and then via phpMyAdmin and they are the same. Just wondering if you saw something different?

Comment: I am not. And apparently few haven't so far. The SQL query executed by MySQL engine and the one that you see in phpMyAdmin is probably different. phpMyAdmin does its best, but in the end, it is a interface. If you tell the MySQL demon to log your queries, you will have the exact queries that are executed by MySQL. No interface in-between.

Comment: (I am just writing that to double-double check with you that it is the same MySQL engine executing the queries, that nothing is cached, modified or anything in between. :) )

Answer (score 1):

I think, the queries are different.

Do a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on `$stmt` to get the exact query being executed via php to be sure the regex part is going as it is and not getting tweaked in middle by any other operations like `bind`.